# popover-append-to-body attribute for a popover element doesn't seem to work in angular-ui

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, popover, angular-ui

I am using angular UI. ([docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), [github](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap))

I would like to make a popover that is appended on body.

- In pure bootstrap, you have to use `container: 'body'` so that your popover is appended on the body element instead of the parent element of your popover. (see http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#popovers)
- In Angular UI, you are supposed to use `popover-append-to-body` (see http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover).

But I tried this attribute, and my popover is not appended on body. (Note that other attributes, such as `placement='right'` do work.)

Html for the popover:

```
<a popover="click me" popover-placement='bottom' popover-append-to-body='true'>
  popover text
</a>
```

Note: In the [source](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/popover/popover.js), I don't find anything related to `popover-append-to-body`

Answer (score 6):

It looks like it works with the latest version of angular ui.

In [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Vqx5m8k31TlSo9KcV6AZ) it does work. (click run, then click `dynamicPopoverText`, then inspect popover and see that it's indeed just below `body`).

Edit: the problem was that in my project, I was using angular-ui 0.1.0 instead of angular-ui 0.4.0

Comment: Please also note that the latest version of the angular-ui/bootstrap, at the time of writing is 0.7.0: http://plnkr.co/edit/t15wtS7Ld4vRNM1NL2BM?p=preview